# How to disable warning pop up in outlook add in

Tags: outlook, office-js

How do you disable this kind of pop up in office add in?

[image: Pop up]

Thanks

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you provided more context, such as when / what actions/code cause the popup to appear. Also, the screen shot appears to be incomplete. FWIW however this appears to be a security-related warning to the user. Security warnings can't be disabled - for understandable reasons...

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact a very much valid question and a good one. We have a work item to improve this experience and reduce the cases where it would appear only to commands that have `ExecuteFunction` action. When the improvement is implemented, it will be possible to completely avoid this pop up for add-ins that use `displayDialogAsync` API from `ShowTaskPane` action commands for cases where the `displayDialogAsync` API call is made from some user control click handler. I can't provide the timeline for when this improvement will be implemented, but we do have it in our backlog.